# Unable to change magento2 theme in the Backend Design Configuration

Tags: php, magento, themes, magento2, magento-2.0

I have installed a new theme on magento2, but unable to switch to other theme options. The following screenshot is the error encountered when trying to change the applied theme option.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should edit "Main website" in Design Configuration.
I think it's second row in Design Configuration table